# Can't edit text with JCE edito after installing community builder

Tags: joomla-3.6, jce

I have been using JCE for a while but after installing Community Builder I can no longer edit text. The edit box appears but it is empty and the on/off switch doesn't make any difference. For now I use TinyMCE editor which works OK. 
Joomla 3.6.5
JCE edit 2.6.2

[image: image of JCE editor problem]

Comment: To understand the problem a bit more, perhaps try using firebug or some other web development tool to see if any errors are displayed when you edit with JCE. I might also try reinstalling JCE. What version of community builder did you install?

Comment: Try upgrading Community Builder and JCE Editor to the latest versions e.g. JCE Editor 2.6.4 is available now.